# 2011 Ford F-250 brake pedal goes to floor when pushed after driving at high speeds above 60 mph

Tags: brakes

After driving for a few minutes above 60 mph when you apply the brakes the pedal goes to the floor. Pedal returns when pumped. All other times the brakes work fine. Took to Ford dealer they said it was the ABS system and made repairs. Drove truck again on the highway it happened again. Took back to Ford and they could not find anything wrong. Happened again.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Was any hard cornering involved during time period?

Comment: Where they lots of hard braking in between? And when last did you change the brake fluid? I have experienced this before in a different vehicle, after driving really slow for several miles, the brake feel went back to normal. I then checked the brake fluid, it was discolored, due to age and several cycles of overheating from hard stopping. Ever since I drained the brake fluid and replaced with new fluid, I have not experienced those symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when the pedal goes to the floor and then the pressure returns after being pumped a couple of times it means you have air in your braking system.
I recommend bleeding your brakes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need brake bleeding. When there is ia air in the system you have to pump the pedal few times to make them work. I just wonder why mechanics didn't do this already, it's quite simple procedure.